# Writing list comprehension nicer

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way to write this list comprehension

```
moves = [m for m in moves if m[0] in range(8) and m[1] in range(8)]
```

in a nicer/more efficient way?

`moves` is a list of tuples and should only contain values that are in 0-7

Tuples it should contain: (0, 0), (0, 1) .... (7, 7)

Tuples it should not contain: (-1, 0), (0, -2), (8, 3) .....

Comment: What is `moves`? Pls specify.

Comment: Define your range object outside the comprehension . Or use a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to avoid redundancy:

```
moves = [m for m in moves if all(0 <= x < 8 for x in m)]
```

Comment: is this faster?moves = [m for m in moves if all(0 <= x <= 7 for x in m)]

Comment: @A.Bau Your suggestion should be faster!

Comment: @schwobaseggl I don't have time to get deeper into it, but I took a quick look at several options: `set`, `endpoints`, and `range` and `set` seems like it might have a tiny bit of an edge over just checking against `endpoints`... but the timing loop might also have some caching that could be messing things up. hmm. fun stuff!

Comment: Either way the performance difference is negligible-- algorithmically they're all the same. Focus on structure,  correctness and clarity,  and don't micro-optimize!

Comment: And time it **with your typical data**.  I think you'll find using a set is about 10x faster than this approach, `all` has a high overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
moves = [m for m in moves if 0 <= m[0] <= 7 and 0 <= m[1] <= 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything more about what is already in `moves`...

This should clean up the code a bit...

```
r = range(8)

moves = [m for m in moves if m[0] in r and m[1] in r]
```

Alternate options, as noted by @schwobaseggl is to use the `all()` function:

```
moves = [m for m in moves if all(x in r for x in m)]
```

If you want things to move a little faster, then eliminating the function call and the generator process associated with range by simply testing for inclusion between two points will save some time...

```
moves = [m for m in moves if all(0 <= x < 8 for x in m)]
```

But converting the range to a set might save even more time. More sophisticated checks should be conducted, if you really need to get fast.

## USING A RANGE

```
In [7]: %%timeit moves = [(-1, 0), (2, 3), (-9, 0)]; r = range(8)
   ...: moves = [m for m in moves if all(x in r for x in m)]
   ...:
The slowest run took 6.65 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 978 ns per loop
```

## USING TWO ENDPOINTS

```
In [8]: %%timeit moves = [(-1, 0), (2, 3), (-9, 0)]; r = range(8)
   ...: moves =[m for m in moves if all(0 <= x < 8 for x in m)]
   ...:
   ...:
The slowest run took 7.31 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 768 ns per loop
```

## USING A SET

```
In [9]: %%timeit moves = [(-1, 0), (2, 3), (-9, 0)]; r = set(range(8))
   ...: moves =[m for m in moves if all(x in r for x in m)]
   ...:
   ...:
The slowest run took 7.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 763 ns per loop
```

Comment: @wim: thanks for identifying the fact that I missed using the r variable in my code about the `sets`. Oops.
to clarify... In IPython, if you use %timeit, it takes all the code and parses it during the timing loops... but with %%timeit (two percent marks), it takes the code on the first line and uses that as 'set up' code, which is executed initially and is NOT parsed during the timing loop.

Answer (score 0):

Gathering some of the excellent suggestions above, I had run a few benchmarks

```
import random

N = 1000
R = 50

# generating pseudo-random input
random.seed(0)
moves = [tuple(random.randint(-R, R) for i in range(2)) for _ in range(N)]
```

#### @A.Bau (original question)

```
%timeit [m for m in moves if m[0] in range(8) and m[1] in range(8)]
340 µs ± 1.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### @schwobaseggl

```
%timeit [m for m in moves if all(0 <= x < 8 for x in m)]
583 µs ± 2.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### @user6731765

```
%timeit [m for m in moves if 0 <= m[0] <= 7 and 0 <= m[1] <= 7]
77.2 µs ± 251 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### @E. Ducateme / 1

```
r = range(8)
%timeit [m for m in moves if m[0] in r and m[1] in r]
120 µs ± 509 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### @E. Ducateme / 2

```
r = range(8)
%timeit [m for m in moves if all(x in r for x in m)]
630 µs ± 5.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### @E. Ducateme / 3

```
r = set(range(8))
%timeit [m for m in moves if m[0] in r and m[1] in r]
62 µs ± 303 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### @wim

```
valid_moves = {(x, y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)}
%timeit [m for m in moves if m in valid_moves]
60.2 µs ± 143 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### @wim (modified to work even if `m` is unhashable, e.g. a list)

```
valid_moves = {(x, y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)}
%timeit [m for m in moves if tuple(m) in valid_moves]
220 µs ± 9.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### @wim (modified to work even if `m` is unhashable - no `tuple` call)

```
valid_moves = {(x, y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)}
%timeit [(x, y) for x, y in moves if (x, y) in valid_moves]
92.7 µs ± 1.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### Summary

Based on these tests should be able to make a more informed choice of what to choose for your particular problem.

If the number of elements in `m` will always be fixed @wim's approach is one of the fastest and fairly readable:

```
valid_moves = {(x, y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)}
moves = [m for m in moves if m in valid_moves]
```

If the number of elements of `m` is unknown (eventually variable), then @E.Ducateme's approach gives reasonably fast results and good readability:

```
r = set(range(8))
moves = [m for m in moves if all(x in r for x in m)]
```

But you should ultimately test the methods with your input, if you are really concerned with raw speed.

Comment: Right, it really affects your method. On the other hand, there is no indication that `m` will be a tuple in the original question. Anyway I corrected for that.

Comment: My bad, did not refresh page.